# ASP.Net DataView Filter clarification

Tags: asp.net, dataview

When i Filter a DataView

```
someView.RowFilter = "ID<>'A22' and isnull(IsVerified,0)=0"
```

What is the logic behind `isnull(IsVerified,0)=0`?

Does it mean the column IsVerified is null or does it check the column IsVerified not null ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `IsNull(IsVerified,0)` call checks the IsVerified value for Null, and if it is null, returns 0, otherwise it returns the value of IsVerified. So since it is then comparing that with 0, your row will be selected if IsVerified has the value of 0 or null.

More about IsNull function [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx).